# cx-oracle: getting the number of deleted records

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle, dml, rowcount

> Is there a simple way to get the number of deleted records in cx
> Oracle?

Using the `rowcount` cursor attribute does not work (it is always zero).

I'm using `cx-Oracle 7.0.0.`

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can still use `rowcount` attribute of `cursor` class without problem in such a way stated below ;

```
import cx_Oracle
conn = cx_Oracle.connect('uname/pwd@host:port/dbname')

param_list=[[101],[102],[103]]
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.prepare('DELETE tab WHERE id =:1')
cursor.executemany(None,param_list)
conn.commit()

print( 'Number Of Deleted Records : ', cursor.rowcount )
```